# how to find and grep specific file in remote server and rsync them

Tags: grep, find, rsync

I have some log files in remote server and analyse them.

I usually download them to my local pc and find some files which have specific text in.

and my commands like this:

```
rsync -avg host:path/*20141223* .
find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep "text text1" {} +
```

(files are gz format)

Here is my question:
I want to download only some files which contain specific text not all files from server.

Please give some advises to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
rsync -avg "$(
    ssh host find /path -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -l "text text1" {} + |
        | sed 's@\.*/path@host::module@' 
)" .
```

Comment: I missed to add module to hostname, it would be: rsync -avg host::ACCESS_PHP/path/*20141223* .